# Solr indexing on multi schemas (databases)

Tags: solr, multi-tenant, solrj

In our multi-tenant application we have multiple databases, one DB for each company. All users of one company access the same database. I have to implement Solr indexing, can I implement Solr indexing using a single core and create multiple shards wherein one shard for one company. Or do I need multiple cores, wherein each core is created for individual company. Basically I am reading a table in DB, to fetch the file path on each record and then accessing the file system to read the file for indexing.

Comment: i will do it 1 core per 1 company/database

Comment: Thanks @ Mysterion, can you also please let me know the pros and cons that should I implement Solr as a single instance or as cloud. I got to implement Solr on SAS application which is not on a cloud.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's put it into the answer. As you described the problem, I think you should create 1 core per 1 company/database, it will be easier for you later on, to restrict users of one company to have access only to their data.

Second, on SolrCloud vs. single instance. A lot depends on the size of the data and desired performance. Quote from the Solr wiki:

> Apache Solr includes the ability to set up a cluster of Solr servers
>   that combines fault tolerance and high availability. Called SolrCloud,
>   these capabilities provide distributed indexing and search
>   capabilities, supporting the following features:
>
> - Central configuration for the entire cluster
> - Automatic load balancing and fail-over for queries
> - ZooKeeper integration for cluster coordination and configuration.

So, if you need those things, and I assume you are, I will prefer SolrCloud over single instance.